# Two constructors in one class C#

Tags: c#

I have a problem in class, I have two constructors in that class, one has no parameters and one which get two parameters. Well, both constructors have the same name so when I try to call the constructor in Program it's calling an error in constructors name which is reasonable because I have the same constructors in one class. In task tells me that I need to write two constructors, one with parameters and one which not get parameters which I said before. The name of the class is Artikal (engl. Article) and two parameters Naziv (engl. Name) and Količina (engl. Amount). My question is how can I solve this problem and can I rename some constructor in another name? Here is my code.

Program.cs

```
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Artikl artikl = Artikl("Pivo", 50);
            Console.WriteLine(artikl.naziv);
            Console.WriteLine(artikl.kolicina);
        }
    }
}
```

Artikal.cs

```
namespace Zadatak_1
{
    class Artikal
    {
        public string naziv { get; set; }
        public int kolicina { get; set; }

        public Artikl(string Naziv, int Kolicina)
        {
            this.naziv = Naziv;
            this.kolicina = Kolicina;
        }
        public Artikl() { }
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. The name used in the constructor must match the name of the type exactly. Your's are different. 2. When instatiating a type (creating an instance) you must use the keyword `new`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the keyword `new` before your instantiation of the `Artikl` class.

However, you can get rid of the constructor with the parameters and assign the values inline with the declaration of the `Artikl` object.

```
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Artikal artikal = new Artikal {
              naziv ="Pivo", 
              kolicina  = 50
            };

            Console.WriteLine(artikal.naziv);
            Console.WriteLine(artikal.kolicina);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I totally forget and didn't realize that I forget to write new, you help me a lot, thank you.

Comment: Also the class is called `Artikal` but the constructors are named `Artikl`

Comment: @Josh, good catch.